# With manually installed Kubernetes, how to install and use addon manager?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

With manually installed Kubernetes [on CoreOS](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html), how does one install and use the [Kubernetes addon manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager)?

I've found references to the addon manager being the current standard way of installing Kubernetes addons, but I can't find any authoritative documentation on it. Hoping someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addon manager is deployed as a normal pod or a deployment, with a simple `kubectl apply -f`.

The yaml looks something like this, look at the specific version that you need:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-addon-manager
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    component: kube-addon-manager
spec:
hostNetwork: true
containers:
- name: kube-addon-manager
  # When updating version also bump it in:
  # - cluster/images/hyperkube/static-pods/addon-manager-singlenode.json
  # - cluster/images/hyperkube/static-pods/addon-manager-multinode.json
  # - test/kubemark/resources/manifests/kube-addon-manager.yaml
  image: gcr.io/google-containers/kube-addon-manager:v6.4-beta.1
  command:
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - /opt/kube-addons.sh 1>>/var/log/kube-addon-manager.log 2>&1
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 5m
      memory: 50Mi
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/
    name: addons
    readOnly: true
  - mountPath: /var/log
    name: varlog
    readOnly: false
volumes:
- hostPath:
    path: /etc/kubernetes/
  name: addons
- hostPath:
    path: /var/log
  name: varlog
```

The addon manager observes the specific yaml files under `/etc/kubernetes/addons/`, put any addon you like here to install it.

Comment: Thanks! What benefits does the addon manager bring compared to installing addons directly?

Comment: Addons are part of the cluster, and deploy the files into the host simplify the integration with any configuration manager. But more interesting, it ensure the status of the file vs the status in the cluster. So, before RBAC if an user modify the dns, etc. the addon manager will restore the description base on the local file system.